# Can't get applet to read text file

Tags: java, permissions, policy

I've tried to get my Java Applet to read from my text file, but I do not have sufficient privaleges to read the file when i run the applet in my browser.
I have tried to use policy files but I cannot seem to get them to work.

I later tried

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "*filelocation*");
```

but i got this error

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission        java.security.policy write)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(Unknown Source)
at BIT.init(BIT.java:35)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What ways can I get my applet to run in my browser? It works fine in Eclipse's applet viewer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is specified within the [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html). It clearly specifies that:

> Applets that are not signed are restricted to the security sandbox,
>   and run only if the user accepts the applet. Applets that are signed
>   by a certificate from a recognized certificate authority can either
>   run only in the sandbox, or can request permission to run outside the
>   sandbox. In either case, the user must accept the applet's security
>   certificate, otherwise the applet is blocked from running.

Later it states that:

> Sandbox applets cannot perform the following operations:
>
> - They cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem, executable files, system clipboard, and printers.
> - They cannot connect to or retrieve resources from any third party server (any server other than the server it originated from).
> - They cannot load native libraries.
> - They cannot change the SecurityManager.
> - They cannot create a ClassLoader.
> - **They cannot read certain system properties. See System Properties for a list of forbidden system properties.**

To know about how to sign an Applet look here : [How to Sign Applets Using RSA-Signed Certificates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You really ought to consider signing the applet.

This (short!) FAQ discusses both policies and signing:

- http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem

Here is the offician documentation:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/doprivileged.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

And here is a good (albeit old) tutorial:

- http://faculty.kutztown.edu/spiegel/CSc421/SigningAnApplet.htm