# Maze generator applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

This is a simple maze generator in which the program asks the user to input the size of the maze through the console and displays the maze through an applet .. i would like to input the size through a text field in a form .. how would i be able to do that?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class hexagonal extends Applet implements Runnable
{

    public static final int TOPL = 1;
    public static final int TOPR = 2;
    public static final int RIGHT = 4;
    public static final int BOTTOMR = 8;
    public static final int BOTTOML = 16;
    public static final int LEFT = 32;

    int cells[][];
    Point current_cell;
    Stack hold;
    int total, count;
    int gridw, gridh, cellw, cellh;
    boolean finished = false;

    Image offscreen;
    Graphics offgr;
    Thread t;

    public void init()
    {
        int x, y;
        Scanner uInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of your hexagonal maze: ");
        gridw = uInput.nextInt(); // 10
        gridh = uInput.nextInt(); // 8
        cellw = 30;
        cellh = (int)(0.866*cellw); // approx. regular hexagon

        cells = new int[gridw][gridh];

        int full = TOPL | TOPR | RIGHT | BOTTOMR | BOTTOML | LEFT;
        for (x = 0; x < gridw; x++)
            for (y = 0; y < gridh; y++)

        int top = (TOPL | TOPR) << 6;
        int bottom = (BOTTOML | BOTTOMR) << 6;
        for (x = 0; x < gridw; x++)
        {
            cells[x][0] |= top;
            cells[x][gridh-1] |= bottom;
        }

        int left = (LEFT | BOTTOML) << 6;
        int right = (RIGHT | TOPR) << 6;
        for (y = 0; y < gridh; y++)
        {
            cells[0][y] |= left;
            cells[gridw-1][y] |= right;
        }

        total = gridw*gridh;
        offscreen = createImage(432, 237);
        offgr = offscreen.getGraphics();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        t.stop();
        t = null;
    }

    public void run()
        {
            int dir;

            current_cell = new Point(rnd(gridw)-1,rnd(gridh)-1);
            count = 1;
            hold = new Stack();
            while (count < total)
            {
                dir = findNewNbr(current_cell);

                if (dir == 0)
                    current_cell = (Point)(hold.pop());
                else
                {
                    removeWall(current_cell, dir);
                    count++;
                    hold.push(current_cell);
                    current_cell = getNbr(current_cell, dir);
                }


                if(total == count)
                    finished = true;

                repaint();
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(0);
                } catch (Exception e) {};
            }

            repaint();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        paint(offgr);
        g.drawImage(offscreen,0,0,this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        int val, x , y;

        int basex = 10;
        int basey = 10;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, gridw*cellw+(cellw+1)*gridh/2, (gridh+2)*cellh);
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        int x1=0, x2=0, x3=0, y1=0, y2=0, y3=0, y4=0;
        for (x = 0; x < gridw; x++)
            for (y = 0; y < gridh; y++)
            {
                val = cells[x][y];

                x1 = basex + x*cellw + y*cellw/2;
                x2 = x1 + cellw/2;
                x3 = x1 + cellw;
                y1 = basey + y*cellh;
                y2 = y1 + cellh/3;
                y3 = y1 + cellh;
                y4 = y1 + 4*cellh/3;
                if ((val & TOPL) != 0)
                    g.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y1);
                if ((val & TOPR) != 0)
                    g.drawLine(x2, y1, x3, y2);
                if ((val & LEFT) != 0)
                    g.drawLine(x1, y2, x1, y3);
                if ((val & RIGHT) != 0)
                    g.drawLine(x3, y2, x3, y3);
                if ((val & BOTTOML) != 0)
                    g.drawLine(x1, y3, x2, y4);
                if ((val & BOTTOMR) != 0)
                    g.drawLine(x2, y4, x3, y3);
            }

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            if ((count < total) && (current_cell != null))
                g.fillOval(current_cell.y*(x3-x2)+basex+current_cell.x*cellw, basey+current_cell.y*cellh+4,
                    cellw, cellh);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            if(finished == true)
            g.drawString("-", 430/2 -20, 230);
    }


        int findNewNbr(Point p)
    {

        int full = TOPL | TOPR | RIGHT | BOTTOMR | BOTTOML | LEFT;
        int d = rnd(6)-1;
        int k = 0;
        while (k < 6)
        {
            switch(d)
            {
                case 0: 
                    if ((cells[p.x][p.y] & (TOPL<<6)) != 0) break;

                    if ((cells[p.x][p.y-1] & 0x3F) == full) return TOPL;
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    if ((cells[p.x][p.y] & (TOPR<<6)) != 0) break;
                    if ((cells[p.x+1][p.y-1] & 0x3F) == full) return TOPR;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    if ((cells[p.x][p.y] & (RIGHT<<6)) != 0) break;
                    if ((cells[p.x+1][p.y] & 0x3F) == full) return RIGHT;
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    if ((cells[p.x][p.y] & (BOTTOMR<<6)) != 0) break;
                    if ((cells[p.x][p.y+1] & 0x3F) == full) return BOTTOMR;
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    if ((cells[p.x][p.y] & (BOTTOML<<6)) != 0) break;
                    if ((cells[p.x-1][p.y+1] & 0x3F) == full) return BOTTOML;
                    break;
                case 5: 
                    if ((cells[p.x][p.y] & (LEFT<<6)) != 0) break;
                    if ((cells[p.x-1][p.y] & 0x3F) == full) return LEFT;
                    break;
            }
            d = (d+1) % 6;
            k++;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void removeWall(Point p, int d)
    {
        cells[p.x][p.y] ^= d;

        switch(d)
        {
            case TOPL: cells[p.x][p.y-1] ^= BOTTOMR;
                break;
            case TOPR: cells[p.x+1][p.y-1] ^= BOTTOML;
                break;
            case RIGHT: cells[p.x+1][p.y] ^= LEFT;
                break;
            case BOTTOMR: cells[p.x][p.y+1] ^= TOPL;
                break;
            case BOTTOML: cells[p.x-1][p.y+1] ^= TOPR;
                break;
            case LEFT: cells[p.x-1][p.y] ^= RIGHT;
                break;
        }
    }

    Point getNbr(Point p, int d)
    {

        switch(d)
        {
            case TOPL: return new Point(p.x, p.y-1);
            case TOPR: return new Point(p.x+1, p.y-1);
            case RIGHT: return new Point(p.x+1, p.y);
            case BOTTOMR: return new Point(p.x, p.y+1);
            case BOTTOML: return new Point(p.x-1, p.y+1);
            case LEFT: return new Point(p.x-1, p.y);
        }
        return null; // This shouldn't ever happen
    }

    int rnd(int n)
        {
            return (int)(Math.random()*n+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial how to read file that is hosted in Applet](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/applet_readfile.htm)

Check below link to read file in java applet

[Can't get applet to read text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255472/cant-get-applet-to-read-text-file)

To read file on local host follow below link

http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem